# Can I figure out $E(X)$ from $E(X^2)$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have an expression for $E(X^2)$, how can I get $E(X)$?

Comment: You can't, unless you have more information.   In general, the variance is given by $E[X^2]-E[X]^2$ so, if you know the variance you can do it.

Comment: I know the variance of $X^2$ but that's it. I tried using that but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: @lulu Technically that still only tells us $|E(X)|$, but we might e.g. also know $X\ge0$.

Comment: @J.G.  Good point.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the distributions given by $P_1(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2}$ on $(0, \infty)$ and $P_2(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2}$ on $(-\infty,\infty)$. Both have second moment $E[X^2] = \frac{1}{2}$, but the mean of $P_1$ is positive since it is defined on $(0,\infty)$ and the mean of $P_2$ is $0$.

If you know $E[X^2]$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$, you have that $$|E[X]| = \sqrt{E[X^2] - \operatorname{Var}(X)}$$ so if you have some information on the random variable (for example, if it was strictly positive) then you can determine $E[X]$.